# extracting key from element in array

Tags: java, arrays, priority-queue

Suppose I have an array A of elements E that each contain an integer key and some object data.
I want extract the key for the i's element of the array A, and compare to some value like

```
   A[i].key>somevalue
```

The problem is I don't know the correct operation to perform this comparison. 
In my program, I can access the key of an element by typing

```
           E.key
```

An since the i's element of A seems to be an element E I would think the first snippet would work, however it does not.

The elements are declared as

```
     public class Element {

         public int key;
         public Object data;

         public Element(int i, Object o){
         this.key = i;
         this.data = o;
         }
     }
```

Constructor for the array
       public class PQHeap implements PQ {
       //constructor
    private PQHeap[] pq;

```
    public PQHeap(int maxElms){
    pq = new PQHeap[maxElms];
}
   ...
```

Some method

```
   private void IncreaseKey(Element e){
    if (e.key < pq[i].key){
                System.out.println("new key is larger than current key");
        }
```

For example, the line with the if statement, the error is "key cannot be resolved or is not a field" 
Operations like pq.length work fine, and e.key in itself also works

Comment: Show us how your variables are declared, and tell us precisely **how** it doesn't work. You get a precise error message from the compiler or the runtime. Paste it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the array is declared as

```
PQHeap[] pq;
```

So it doesn't contain `Element` instances, but `PQHeap` instances. So `pq[i]` is of type `PQHeap`, and `PQHeap` doesn't have a `key` field, hence the compilation error.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much, I changed PQHeap[] to Element[] and it now seems to work.